# Obtener datos de un usuario logeado en Android

Tags: php, android

tengo un problema al momento de obtener los datos de un usuario que ha iniciado sesión con su nombre y su contraseña, necesito obtener sus demás datos como el id, apellido, correo, dirección, etc... el problema es que no encuentro forma tanto en PHP como en **Android** para obtenerlos siempre me marca error o datos nulos, este es mi script `PHP` para logearme:

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT id_usuario, nombre_usuario, apellido_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login' AND password = '$password'";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);   

if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo "Ingreso correcto";
} else {
    echo "Usuario no registrado";
}

?>
```

y este es mi código en **Android** (Estoy usando `Volley`):

```
btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        if(ed_login.getText().toString().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ingresa tu nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(ed_password.getText().toString().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ingresa tu contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else{

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere...");

            progressDialog.show();

            str_login = ed_login.getText().toString().trim();
            str_password = ed_password.getText().toString().trim();

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_INGRESO, response -> {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Ingreso correcto")){

                    ed_login.setText("");
                    ed_password.setText("");

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DatosPrincipales.class));

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }, error -> {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            ){
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("login",str_login);
                    params.put("password",str_password);
                    return params;

                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }

    });
```

El **login** y el **password** si los obtengo correctamente porque los escribo en el `EditText` pero cuando trato de obtener los demás datos del usuario no lo consigo he tratado de usar `params.get("id_usuario");` en el `HashMap` pero tampoco funciona, espero me puedan instruir de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($_POST);` en el código PHP y haz un Logcat del response de Volley en Android y dinos qué muestra. Lo primero aquí sería verificar que hay comunicación cliente/servidor y revisar los datos que se están enviando. Además, si da error, dí exactamente qué error, agregando a la pregunta dicho mensaje de error.

Comment: @A.Cedano el var_dump me muestra esto: array(0) { } y en volley el response me muestra esto: {
      ["password"]=>
      string(4) "0207"
      ["login"]=>
      string(6) "adiel"
    } y lo otro no es tanto error mas bien es un dato nulo por ejemplo si yo creo una variable estatica a la cual le seteo params.get("id_usuario"); por ejemplo idUsuario = params.get("id_usuario"); y en otra pantalla trato de setear ese idUsuario en el logcat me muestra "null"

Comment: Me has liado con tu comentario. Simplemente quiero saber si esto: `{ ["password"]=> string(4) "0207" ["login"]=> string(6) "adiel" }` es la salida del `var_dump($_POST);` o no.  O si la salida es esta: `array(0) { } ` en cuyo caso los datos no se estarían enviando por POST como supones. **Ese es el punto crucial** que se debe depurar ahora: ¿los datos se envían sí o no?

Comment: @A.Cedano NO, esa es la salida del response en Android, en PHP la salida del var_dump($_POST); es: array(0) { }

Comment: ¿A qué corresponde esto exactamente entonces: `{ ["password"]=> string(4) "0207" ["login"]=> string(6) "adiel" }`? ¿Qué pusiste para que eso salga? Me refiero a cuando pusiste: `Log.d("LOQUESEA",unObjeto);`  quiero saber lo que pusiste en `unObjeto` que está dando ese `var_dump`

Comment: @A.Cedano nada mas hice un System.out.print(response); para imprimir cual era la respuesta que me manda Volley y eso es lo que me manda

Comment: A ver, no puede haber dos salidas, por un lado un array vacío y por otro lado un array con datos (a no ser que tengas otro `var_dump`  en el archivo `conexion.php`). No entiendo. Por otra parte, ¿no ves nada que diga `Usuario correcto` o `Usuario incorrecto`? Me refiero a tus depuraciones en Android. Si la llamada a tu archivo está funcionando debería imprimir uno de esos dos mensajes.

Comment: En el planteamiento de la pregunta tampoco queda claro dónde te marca error o datos nulos ¿? En el caso de que todo estuviera OK, lo que ocurriría sería esto: `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DatosPrincipales.class));` Iniciarías otra Activity sin más. ¿De dónde piensas sacar los datos, en caso de que lo que quieras sea mostrarlos en esa nueva Activity? Si es eso, deberás pasar los datos con el Intent para poder tenerlos en la otra Activity. Además, en tu código PHP no devuelves los datos que dices querer mostrar (nombre, apellido, etc).

Comment: Creo que hay un planteamiento inconcluso en tu PHP, ¿Estás usando PDO o MySQLi?  Otra cosa que noto es que no estas parametrizando, que no estas hasheando la contraseña, que tu echo solo imprime el "Ingreso Correcto" mas no la pass ni el usuario.